# get count of string with commas and split them

Tags: java

I am new to java . I have this String.

```
str="plane,cat,red,dogy";
```

I want to make a loop and send the data . the below is wrong but i want something similar to it.

```
for ( int i = 0; i>str.length; i++)
{
str=split.string(,);
 // i know it wrong but I want to get the result before comma, for example first loop plane, second loop cat third loop red and so on
updatestatement(str);
}
```

Comment: This should do: `String [] words=split.string(",");`. But what do you mean by "send the data" and what is `updatestatement(str)` doing?

Comment: it should be str.split(","). and this gives you the array of string so to hold this define a variable of type string array

Comment: @FrankPuffer this method will do update on the database , i want to send paramter to this update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
String str="plane,cat,red,dogy";
for(String subString: str.split(",")){
   updatestatement(subString);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] words= str.split(",");

for (String w : words){

//Do whatever you want with each word
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `for` to split. Just:

```
String[] parts = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very unclear what you need. But i think you are looking for this:

```
String[] s = str.split(",");

for ( int i = 0; i<s.length; i++)
{
 // i know it wrong but I want to get the result before comma, for example first loop plane, second loop cat third loop red and so on
updatestatement(str);
}
```

Where updatestatement is a method in your class

Comment: I have a string with comma, i dont have array of string

Comment: @Moudiz after Splitting the string you have an Array os strings.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.

```
 String str="plane,cat,red,dogy";
 String[] items = str.split(",");

 System.out.println("No of items::"+items.length);
```

If you want to print each item,

```
    for (String eachItem : items) {
        System.out.println(eachItem);
        //updateStatement(eachItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it as follows :

```
String str="plane,cat,red,dogy";
String[]str1=str.split(",");

    for ( int i = 0; i>str1.length; i++)
    {
    updatestatement(str1[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="plane,cat,red,dogy";
String[] parts = str.split(",");
Arrays.stream(parts).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This solution only works with `Java 8` because of the `stream` method. If you remove the last line it also works with other Java versions.

Comment: You should mark that this solution works only in Java 8 and later